# Doing subtraction on mysql

Tags: mysql

I Have two tables here  `'Sales_order'` and `'payment'`  I want to subtraction `SUM` from column `Grand_total` in `Sales_order` and column amount in `payment`.

Let's say I have , `Amount = 40000` and `grand_total = 40000`
so it should be `Grand_total - Amount = 0`, but when I start my query it show `360000` ?? :(

This is my code:

```
SELECT SUM(payment.amount) - SUM(sales_order.grand_total) AS Total_all 
FROM sales_order, member,payment 
WHERE sales_order.member = '2'
```

And here my tables screenshoot[image: Sales Order]

[image: payment]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
select 
(select SUM(amount) from payment) - 
(select SUM(grand_total) from Sales_order where member = '2')
```

If you need some `where` clauses, add they inside relevant subquery